# T-SQL How to grant role to user with ADMIN/GRANT option in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

After creating roles and granting privileges to them, I want to grant the privileges of a specified role to a user with grant option so that the user can grant privileges to others, how to do with it?

```
GRANT INSERT ON someTable TO rolem_has_some_permissions WITH GRANT OPTION
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'rolem_has_some_permissions', 'sabertazimi'
GO
```

Doing like this can't make 'sabertazimi' to grant his privileges to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure sp_addrolemember has 2(two) parameters only:

```
sp_addrolemember [ @rolename = ] 'role', [ @membername = ] 'security_account'
```

WITH GRANT OPTION has nothing to do with sp_addrolemember, instead it is the option of GRANT.
***edited:***
If you want your role members to be able to grant their permissions to others, you should grant these permissions to the role with the grant option.
When the user has to grant a permission to some other user, he must use the additional AS clause like this:

```
  grant select on myTbl to AnotherUser as MyRole
```

Comment: Thank you for your question, I did not know the answer and I could not find it earlier because this is not written in offline help for SQL Server 2008, I found it only online for 2012, the "as" clause also exists in 2008 but it's not described regarding roles until 2012